# Calculate scrollbar thumtrack size

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a control where I use `SetScrollInfo` (user32) to set the `nMin` and `nMax`. How can I calculate the right size of the `nPage` (or the thumbtrack)? I know it must be some percentage of the client area, but I'm not really sure on the calculation. I am *not* using `AutoScroll` and associated properties so that I can have maximum control over scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the documentation at MSDN ([Scroll Box Position and Scrolling Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787527%28VS.85%29.aspx#scroll_position_and_range)) answers your question. An excerpt:

> You can set a page size for a scroll
>   bar. The page size represents the
>   number of data units that can fit in
>   the client area of the owner window
>   given its current size. For example,
>   if the client area can hold 16 lines
>   of text, an application would set the
>   page size to 16. The system uses the
>   page size, along with the scrolling
>   range and length of the scroll bar
>   shaft, to set the size of the scroll
>   box. Whenever a window containing a
>   scroll bar is resized, an application
>   should call the SetScrollInfo function
>   to set the page size.

Comment: Yup! You are spot on with this. Thanks!